# How to use VirtualHost to host a different regular webpage and TOR webpage?

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost, tor

I want to host a regular website and a TOR website on one apache2 installation. I also use a Let's Encrypt certificate on my normal website. Currently, my 000-default.conf in sites-available file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website1.com
    ServerAlias www.website1.com
    ServerAlias alias.nu
    ServerAlias www.alias.nu
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName torlink.onion
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/torhtml
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I've ran:

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default
sudo a2ensite 000-default
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But whatever I do, whenever I go to the tor link, the regular website shows up (it also prompts me to accept the certificate, since the TOR domain is not added to the certificate, since this is impossible with Let's Encrypt).

I have a feeling it might be because of the RewriteRule, but that should only match the ServerName and ServerAliasses I think.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but it works now. I restarted apache2 and tor, reran some a2dissite and a2ensite and it magically works.

EDIT: I might have found out. I deleted the HTTPS rewrite. My file now looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName Torlink.onion
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/torhtml
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website.com
    ServerAlias www.website.com
    ServerAlias alias.nu
    ServerAlias www.alias.nu
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    Redirect permanent / https://www.website.com
</VirtualHost>
```